# TFS Build skips webfonts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, tfs, msbuild

Recently we started using webfonts in our projects. When we queue build all the files from the project gets copied however TFS build skips the webfonts (extension .woff, .ttf) Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Same question asked at social.msdn.microsoft.com: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d3edda77-de9c-4674-9bac-695131ea8b7e/tfs-build-skips-webfonts?forum=tfsbuild